# How to Calculate the derivative of $\frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm sorry to bother you with this easy problem. But I'm working alone and totally confused.
It is the 1378th Problem from "Problems in Mathematical Analysis" written by Demidovich. The standard answer is
$$\frac{60(1+x)^{99}(1+6x)}{(1-2x)^{41}(1+2x)^{61}}$$

But when I followed the rutine
$$\frac{d(P(x)/Q(x))}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dP(x)}{dx}Q(x)-P(x)\frac{dQ(x)}{dx}}{Q(x)^2}$$
I got
$$\frac{100(1+x)^{99}(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}-(1+x)^{100}(-80(1-2x)^{39}+120(1+2x)^{59})}{(1-2x)^{80}(1+2x)^{120}}$$

and finally
$$\frac{60(1+x)^{99}P(x)}{(1-2x)^{41}(1+2x)^{61}}$$

$$P(x)=1-4x^2-\frac{3(1+x)}{(1-2x)^{39}}-\frac{2(1+x)}{(1+2x)^{59}}$$

Would you tell me what mistake I made. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:)** If you are familiar with logarithm so write
$$y=\frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}$$
and
$$\ln y=100\ln(1+x)-40\ln(1-2x)-60\ln(1+2x)$$
take derivative and simplify!

Comment: It should be noted that this is a “formal method” and doesn't require that the arguments to the logarithm are positive. A proper justification would take quite a long time, however; but, hey, it works!

Comment: @MyGlasses Thank your so much! With logarithm, the problem was sloved in an amazing speed!

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your enlightening :))

Comment: @Alfred You'r welcome!

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your kind reminder. It is quite a problem, but, really, it works! :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can write those equations as
$$\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1-2x}\Biggr)^{40}\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\Biggr)^{60}$$
And use multiplication rule

It is easier this way

> $$\color{green}{\frac{d}{dx} }\Biggr(\color{red}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1-2x}\Biggr)^{40}}\color{blue}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\Biggr)^{60}}\Biggr)$$$$$$$$\color{red}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1-2x}\Biggr)^{40}}\color{green}{\frac{d}{dx}}\color{blue}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\Biggr)^{60}}+\color{green}{\frac{d}{dx}}\color{red}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1-2x}\Biggr)^{40}}\color{blue}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\Biggr)^{60}}$$$$$$$$\color{blue}{60 \Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\Biggr)^{59}\Biggr(\frac{-1}{(1+2x)^2}\Biggr)}\color{red}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1-2x}\Biggr)^{40}}+\color{red}{40\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1-2x}\Biggr)^{39}\Biggr(\frac{3}{(1-2x)^2}\Biggr)}\color{blue}{\Biggr(\frac{1+x}{1+2x}\Biggr)^{60}}$$$$$$$$-60\frac{(1+x)^{99}}{(1+2x)^{\color{blue}{61}}(1-2x)^{\color{red}{40}}}+120\frac{(1+x)^{99}}{(1-2x)^{\color{red}{41}}(1+2x)^{\color{blue}{60}}}$$$$$$$$\frac{60(1+x)^{99}(\color{red}{-1+2x+2+4x})}{(1+2x)^{61}(1-2x)^{41}}$$$$$$$$\frac{60(1+x)^{99}(6x+1)}{(1+2x)^{61}(1-2x)^{41}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer! This is much simplify. I followed your steps and got the right answer. :-D

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: If you wish you may click the check box on my answer

Answer (score 0):

Or write it this way too it's easier

$P(x)=\frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}$

$P(x)=(\frac{(1+x)^{10}}{(1-4x^2)^{4}(1+2x)^{2}})^{10}$

$P(x)=(\frac{(1+x)^{5}}{(1-4x^2)^{2}(1+2x)})^{20}=Q(x)^{20}$

Then apply $Q'(x)^n=nQ(x)^{n-1}Q'(x)$

Comment: Thank you! I'm so stupid, trying to slove the problem so voilent while there are so many clever ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the derivative of the logarithm:

$$y = \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}} \implies \ln y = 100\ln(1+x)-40\ln(1-2x)-60\ln(1+2x)$$

$$\frac{y'}{y} = (\ln y)' = \frac{100}{1+x} + \frac{80}{1-2x} - \frac{120}{1+2x}$$

\begin{align}y' &= y\left(\frac{100}{1+x} + \frac{80}{1-2x} - \frac{120}{1+2x} \right)\\
&= \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}\left(\frac{100}{1+x} + \frac{80}{1-2x} - \frac{120}{1+2x} \right)\\
&= \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}\frac{100(1-4x^2)+80(1+x)(1+2x)-120(1+x)(1-2x)}{(1+x)(1-2x)(1+2x)}\\
&= \frac{(1+x)^{100}}{(1-2x)^{40}(1+2x)^{60}}\frac{60(1+6x)}{(1+x)(1-2x)(1+2x)}\\
&= \frac{60(1+x)^{99}(1+6x)}{(1-2x)^{41}(1+2x)^{61}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! logarithm is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Take first derivative of $\dfrac{(1+x)^a}{(1-2x)^b(1+2x)^c}$ and replace the values of $a,b,c$ in your result. This way could be better for your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$[(1+x)^{100}(1-2x)^{-40}(1+2x)^{-60}]'=$$
$$100(1+x)^{99}(1-2x)^{-40}(1+2x)^{-60}+\\80(1+x)^{100}(1-2x)^{-41}(1+2x)^{-60}-\\120(1+x)^{100}(1-2x)^{-40}(1+2x)^{-61}=$$
$$20(1+x)^{99}(1-2x)^{-41}(1+2x)^{-61}\cdot \\ [5(1-2x)(1+2x)+4(1+x)(1+2x)-6(1+x)(1-2x)]=$$
$$\frac{20(1+x)^{99}}{(1-2x)^{41}(1+2x)^{61}}\cdot3(1+6x.)$$